# Подсчитать количество предметов принадлежащих юзеру

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Имею простую, но немного не до конца для меня понятную задачку по SQL.

Вкратце, у нас есть несколько таблиц, первая, `accounts`, где соответственно, хранится информация в виде "ключ-значение".  Есть ячейки `id, username, email`.

Следующая таблица `items`, в которой хранится `id` предмета, его название и вес.

Третья таблица хранит информацию о связи между первыми двумя и содержит поля `id` предмета и `id` юзера.

Соответственно, конечная таблица должна содержать `user_id, username, items, weight`.

Выводить только если общая сумма веса больше 20.

Вопрос в том, как сделать подсчет предметов на основе их веса. То есть можно объявить переменную, которая будет равна:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(items.id) FROM items INNER JOIN accounts ON items.account_id
```

Но как подсчитать суммарный вес предметов?

Например таблица выглядит так:

```
account_id item_id
1             1
1             3
1             2
1             1
```

```
item_id weight
1          5
2          15
3          25
```

Как запрограммировать подсчёт с помощью языка SQL? Спасибо!

Comment: чтобы получить искомый вывод. надо заджойнить все три таблицы. Чтобы отфильтровать только тех юзеров, у которых больше 20веса, надо либо использовать фильтрацию с подзапросом, либо, что лучше, заджйонить все это добро на производную таблицу, где подсчитать юзеров, суммарный вес, и оставить > 20.

Comment: `select user_id ... group by user_id, having sum(i.w) > 20` даст вам юзеров. пихнете все это в производную таблицу ("подзапрос") и джойните все оставшееся

Comment: @teran а как пристыковать все итемы к конкретному юзер айди , или делать sum(account_id.item_id.weight) ?

Comment: *конечная таблица должна содержать user_id, username, items, weight* С первыми двумя полями понятно. Последнее содержит сумму весов предметов. Но что делать с наименованиями предметов? это не вес, не число, сложить не получится. Конкатенация в CSV? так ты рискуешь получить на выходе такую портянку, что чертям тошно станет. Короче. не надо выводить данные разных уровней группировки вместе. Один запрос на получение суммарного веса, второй на получение списка предметов - один предмет на строку. Так будет читабельно хотя бы...

Comment: @Akina у предметов же есть своя айдишка...

Comment: @Akina я  ж вот и спрашиваю, какого вида должен приобрести запрос, который получает список айтемов линкованых к конретному юзеру, ищущий кол-во определенных предметов, обращающийся в таблицу за значением weight. Я знаю как сделать это на ЯП, но не на sql..

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункт 5, и особенно пункт 3

Answer (score 0):

Например, так

```
select a.id user_id,max(username) username, sum(wt) weight
  ,group_concat(ItemName) Items
from accounts a
left join 
(   -- сколько весит Item и как называется
  select user_id,item_id,item_qty*Itemweight wt,ItemName
  from( -- сколько у user'а каких item
    select user_id,item_id,count(*) item_qty
    from UserItem
    group by user_id,item_id
  )uig
  left join items i on i.id=uig.item_id
) uigw on uigw.user_id=a.id
group by a.id
having sum(wt)>20
```

или так:

```
select a.id user_id,username,weight,items
from accounts a
inner join 
  (
  select user_id,sum(wt) weight,group_concat(ItemName) Items
  from(
    select user_id,item_id,item_qty*Itemweight wt,ItemName
    from(
      select user_id,item_id,count(*) item_qty
      from UserItem
      group by user_id,item_id
      )uig
    left join items i on i.id=uig.item_id
   ) uigw 
   group by user_id
   having sum(wt)>20
)uigws on uigws.user_id=a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать достаточно простым запросом, если вас устраивает, что список предметов будет строкой. По идее, для вашей задачи логичнее было бы сделать его массивом, но я не знаю, работает ли mysql с массивами. В постгрес например есть array_agg, который сделал бы массив из предметов.

Не совсем понятно, как дальше использовать это поле, но если надо, значит надо.
Посмотрите мое решение на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/573daa/3)
Код вот такой:

```
select 
  ui.user_id
  , u.username
  , group_concat(i.id) as items
  , sum(i.weight) as weight
from accounts u
left join user_item ui
  on ui.user_id = u.id
left join items i
  on i.id = ui.item_id
group by ui.user_id, u.username
having sum(i.weight) > 20
```

p.s. перечитал вопрос и понял, что не до конца понятно, что должно лежать в поле items. В моем решении там лежит список предметов пользователя. Вам это и нужно? или нужно количество предметов?

Если нужно количество предметов, то просто замените group_concat на count